# Calculate the time that passed between first row inserted in MySQL and the last

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp, innodb

In a table I have a field of type *timestamp*. How do I calculate the time that has passed between the first row that was inserted and the last row?

The time is stored in this fashion: *2011-09-13 16:32:19*

The table uses the InnoDB engine if it matters! And I will be doing this in PHP.

Comment: Do you need the query, or the PHP logic for this? What have you tried so far? Start by looking at [`TIMEDIFF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff).

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF( MAX(time_col), MIN(time_col) ) FROM [tablename];
```

This will be helpful when it stores in time-sequentially. But timestamp column can be modified by updating, so I suggest the below query than above one.

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF( x.time_col, y.timecol ) FROM 
    ( SELECT time_col FROM [tablename] ORDER BY [primary_key] DESC LIMIT 1 ) x,
    ( SELECT time_col FROM [tablename] ORDER BY [primary_key] ASC  LIMIT 1 ) y
```

---

You can use TIMESTAMPDIFF function either.

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF( SECOND, x.time_col, y.timecol ) FROM 
    ( SELECT time_col FROM [tablename] ORDER BY [primary_key] DESC LIMIT 1 ) x,
    ( SELECT time_col FROM [tablename] ORDER BY [primary_key] ASC  LIMIT 1 ) y
```

Comment: What do you mean time-sequentially?

Comment: It is working, but it returns the just the minutes..i need it to be more accurate such as seconds too.

Comment: I added more description in my answer.

Comment: TIMEDIFF function returns in TIME or DATE-and-TIME expressions. Please check out http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff

Comment: So my field must be datetime? But my field is like i said timestamp, and due the way the the software works, i cannot change the field's type to datetime as i lose the capability of "ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"

Comment: Oh wait, sorry, your code works perfectly. It appears that i inserted a row at the exact same time so the timediff returned 00:29:00 ...what were the odds. After inserting another field i got the result i needed. Thanks ;)

Comment: Nope, you don't have to. I tested above queries on timestamp columns. And it returns that I expected. Or, How about to use 'TIMESTAMPDIFF' function?

Comment: @dikidera It's ok, my pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

this example is using mysql_* function in php,
you can replace to whatever method you are comfortable with

```
$con = mysql_connect(...); // your connection
$sql = <<<SQL
select 
  max(the_field) as last_time ,
  min(the_field) as first_time,
  timestampdiff(second, min(the_field), max(the_field)) as diff_time
from your_table
SQL;
$res = mysql_query($sql, $con);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
mysql_free_result($res);
```